# on ubuntu 22.04 how I know what version of Apache age with postgres 11 I'm using?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I'm using Apache age extension for PostgreSQL and I'm using PostgreSQL version 11 on my system which is Ubuntu 22.04

how I can know the version of Apache AGE using terminal in Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Connect to your PostgreSQL server using the psql command-line client and run `\dx age` command:

```
demo=# \dx age
             List of installed extensions
 Name | Version |   Schema   |      Description       
------+---------+------------+------------------------
 age  | 1.2.0   | ag_catalog | AGE database extension
(1 row)
```

2. You can use an SQL command to fetch the version number of the 'age' extension.

```
demo=# SELECT extversion FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'age';
 extversion 
------------
 1.2.0
(1 row)
```

3. Alternatively, you can run the following directly from the command-line:

```
psql -U <username> -d <database> -c "SELECT extversion FROM pg_extension 
WHERE extname = 'age';"
```

```
 safi@192 postgresql-11.17 % bin/psql -U safi -d demo -c "SELECT extversion 
FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'age';"

 extversion 
------------
 1.2.0
(1 row)
```

Comment: Yes that works for the age version

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following command inside the terminal without getting into a sql session to list your installed extensions and their versions as well. (**MUST having postgresql server running**)

```bash
# test: database name may be something else in your side
psql -c "\dx" test
```

```bash
# output
                 List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |         Description          
---------+---------+------------+------------------------------
 age     | 1.2.0   | ag_catalog | AGE database extension
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the `age.control` file for the version that is currently being used.

A different version can be installed by changing the `default_version` property.

```
default_version = '1.2.0'
comment = 'AGE database extension'
module_pathname = '$libdir/age'

schema = 'ag_catalog'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query

```
SELECT extname, extversion FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'age';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this query, it did work for.

```
SELECT extversion FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'age';
```

1. SELECT extversion: This specifies that we want to retrieve the value of the extversion column.
2. FROM pg_extension: This indicates that we are selecting data from the pg_extension system catalog table.
3. WHERE extname = 'age': This filters the rows in the pg_extension table based on the condition extname = 'age'.

This query should will retrieve the extversion value of the age extension, which indicates the version of Apache AGE installed in PostgreSQL database.